# Python PIP cannot install modules

Tags: windows-10, python, pip

I am trying to install a module from pip on the command line, but every time it gives me this error message:"This app can't run on your PC." I am running Windows 10, and using Python 3.5.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the command `cd "D:\Program Files\Python\Scripts"` did not work.  Reasons:  1) you didn't close the double quotes, 2) you need to switch to the D-drive by just typing `D:`, or 3) did you mean `C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts` (i.e. in the C-drive)?

Comment: No, my C drive is an SSD and I installed python on my D drive (HDD).

Answer (score 0):

As *jehad* has pointed out, you failed to cd to "*D:\Program Files\Python\Scripts*" partly because you didn't end the quotes (though it should work) and partly because you didn't specify the drive D: first. Also a prefered way to install modules using PIP would be to:

***python.exe -m pip install pyperclip***

Try typing command above in admin console and let us know if there is any difference.